# Understanding how LabView buffers work

Tags: memory, framebuffer, labview

I am using LabView for an imaging project. In the code I have two separate while loops running (for the most part) independently. The small dependence -if this is a dependence at all- comes from the fact that the first loop is continuously taking an input image and storing it in a temporary buffer; each iteration of the loop replaces what is in this image buffer. Now the second loop takes whatever is in that buffer at the moment an iteration starts and does some processing.

My question: How is a buffer overwritten? Does it replace one pixel's worth of data at at a time? Could the second loop access the buffer while the buffer is in mid-process of being over-written and thus generate a faulty output?

Comment: Can you send a screengrab of your code?

Answer (score 0):

By independent, I am understanding, both the while loops are in serial. It'd be good if you could add a screenshot of the code.

There is *truly* no parallelism in LabVIEW, however it's memory management is really good. When the code is in the first loop, the image will be processed and the execution won't come back to it until the second loop has also processed. That's why they are in serial and there shouldn't be any issue, given that the buffers are allocated correctly, with proper names. Again, your question would make more sense if you could show the code to us.